# Moments around a pivot system

Tags: forces, free-body-diagram

Vane mounting System:

[image]

[image]

Question 1: Take the moments about P for (a):

My answer: $Sb = g(aM + cm)$ Though I think this is wrong since I don't know how to incorporate the $P$ force.

Question 2: Take the moments about P for (b):

My answer: $Sb + Ra = (x+a)Mg + cMg $

Can anyone help me, this is really bugging me. Note I am aware that for a normal pivot system, the force that an object of mass $M$ applies on the pivot is the weight of that object multiplied by the distance $r$ from the centre of mass of the pivot.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers look correct to me. When you are pivoting about a point $P$, the forces acting through $P$ don't contribute a moment (since the distance of the arm = 0 for them). Since the moments are zero, you can omit them from your expression.